# Find the row violating the constraint to be added

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, check-constraints

I'm trying to add a check constraint to a table like

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT bar CHECK (...);
```

and I get the error:

```
ERROR:  check constraint "bar" is violated by some row
********** Error **********

ERROR: check constraint "bar" is violated by some row
SQL state: 23514
```

Is there a way to have postgres (9.6) tell me at which row it fails? It would help a lot.

Comment: I would love to be proven wrong, but I don't think there is a way.  `on conflict` does not work for check constraints.

Comment: There sure is.  Select * from bar where *<desired check constraint>*;

Comment: What is your `CHECK`?

Comment: @DigvijayS it calls a custom plpgsql function that validates json data.

Comment: @Belayer good idea, i think it should work that way.

Comment: @Belayer It solves my problem, if you want you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There sure is.

```
Select * from bar where NOT <desired check constraint>;
```

Comment: Just to be accurate, the correct statement is: `select * from foo where NOT <desired check constraint>`. My edit was discarded so I could only comment.